# class extension not being called - unable to configure annotations on map

Tags: swift, mapkit

I'm on Swift 5 and Xcode 11, currently trying to create a map with predefined annotations using custom images instead of the default markers. I've been playing around with Apple's sample code for [AnnotatingMapWithCustomData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapkit_annotations/annotating_a_map_with_custom_data) and could tailor it to what I needed. But once I tried to copy the code into my own project, the annotations showed up as default markers instead of the custom annotationViews I configured.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    private var allAnnotations: [MKAnnotation]?

    private var displayedAnnotations: [MKAnnotation]? {
        willSet {
            if let currentAnnotations = displayedAnnotations {
                mapView.removeAnnotations(currentAnnotations)
            }
        }
        didSet {
            if let newAnnotations = displayedAnnotations {
                mapView.addAnnotations(newAnnotations)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        registerMapAnnotationViews()

        // Create the array of annotations and the specific annotations for the points of interest.
        allAnnotations = [ShrekAnnotation(), CoffeeAnnotation()]

        // Dispaly all annotations on the map.
        displayedAnnotations = allAnnotations
        centerMapOnLondon()
    }

    /// - Tag: RegisterAnnotationViews
    private func registerMapAnnotationViews() {
        mapView.register(MKAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(ShrekAnnotation.self))
        mapView.register(MKAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(CoffeeAnnotation.self))
    }

    private func centerMapOnLondon() {
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507911, longitude: -0.132222)
        mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: span), animated: true)
    }
}

extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

    /// - Tag: CreateAnnotationViews
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard !annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) else {
            // Make a fast exit if the annotation is the `MKUserLocation`, as it's not an annotation view we wish to customize.
            return nil
        }

        var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?

        if let annotation = annotation as? ShrekAnnotation {
            annotationView = setupShrekAnnotationView(for: annotation, on: mapView)
        } else if let annotation = annotation as? CoffeeAnnotation {
            annotationView = setupCoffeeAnnotationView(for: annotation, on: mapView)
        }

        return annotationView
    }

    /// - Tag: ConfigureAnnotationViews
    private func setupShrekAnnotationView(for annotation: ShrekAnnotation, on mapView: MKMapView) -> MKAnnotationView {
        let reuseIdentifier = NSStringFromClass(ShrekAnnotation.self)
        let view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: annotation)

        view.canShowCallout = true

        // Provide the annotation view's image.
        let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "map-shrek1")
        view.image = image

        return view
    }

    /// - Tag: ConfigureAnnotationViews
    private func setupCoffeeAnnotationView(for annotation: CoffeeAnnotation, on mapView: MKMapView) -> MKAnnotationView {
        let reuseIdentifier = NSStringFromClass(CoffeeAnnotation.self)
        let view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: annotation)

        view.canShowCallout = true

        // Provide the annotation view's image.
        let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "map-cof1")
        view.image = image

        return view
    }
}
```

Apparently the class extension is not being called but I don't know how to fix this. The code that worked before I tried implementing it in my own project is identical. Could I have missed something I should've copied too or can you find the reason for the bug in the code?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't see you setting `mapView.delegate = self` is it missing in code sample pasted above or you missed it in code hence delegates are not being called?

Comment: yep, I forgot that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not setting the mapView delegate hence `viewFor annotation` is not being triggered and your custom annotation view is not appearing on map. Set

`mapView.delegate = self`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self
    registerMapAnnotationViews()

    // Create the array of annotations and the specific annotations for the points of interest.
    allAnnotations = [ShrekAnnotation(), CoffeeAnnotation()]

    // Dispaly all annotations on the map.
    displayedAnnotations = allAnnotations
    centerMapOnLondon()
}
```

Hope this helps